# Data is not inserted into SQL table using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a table in a sql server database. I am trying to insert data into the table using entity framework but it's not working as expected.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserCompletedWorkouts] (
[Id]        INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[UsersName] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[WorkoutId] INT          NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Model

```
   public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ConfirmedWorkoutModel> ViewWorkout { get; set; }
}
    [Table("UserCompletedWorkouts")]
public class ConfirmedWorkoutModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UsersName { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
}
```

}

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Index(int Id)
    {
        db.ViewWorkout.Add(new ConfirmedWorkoutModel() { WorkoutId = Id,  UsersName = User.Identity.Name});
        return View(db.ViewWorkout.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call SaveChanges() on the context...

```
    db.ViewWorkout.Add(new ConfirmedWorkoutModel() { WorkoutId = Id,  UsersName = User.Identity.Name});
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View(db.ViewWorkout.ToList());
```